# what is the page size in exchange server?

Tags: database, exchange-server, edb

Please tell me what is the page size in each version of MS exchange server i.e. Exchange Server 4.0, Exchange Server 5.0, Exchange 2000 Server, Exchange Server 2003, Exchange Server 2007, Exchange Server 2010, Exchange Server 2013 of MS exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange databases are coming in different page sizes that might differ even within the same version. Just to make sure you use the correct page size you should use the function **JetGetDatabaseFileInfo**, with the Infolevel set to **JET_DbInfoMisc**. This function will return a **JET_DBINFOMISC** structure, which also includes the size of the database you want to examine.

See the complete documentation of this function here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269239%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ask? Curiosity, or are you trying to solve a problem?

While Fotis is correct that JetGetDatabaseFileInfo() will return the correct value, it is not supported to use esent.dll (as documented on MSDN) to read Exchange databases. It may work, but it is not supported.
What is supported is to run `eseutil.exe -mh <database-name>` and look for cbDbPage.

Exchange 2003 and earlier was 4k pages.
I think we did 32k pages for 2007? I don't remember the exact release it was changed.
2010 and 2013 are 32k pages.

-martin

Comment: I wants to solve a problem . I am working on .edb file . I have many EDB file , and i wants to know which file comes from which version . I am opened EDB file in winhex . And read from this http://www.edbsearch.com/edb.html link . In this link it is given that which 0x8 bytes gives the information about version, but how i find it . Please explain .

Comment: The version in the database header refers to the database engine version, which is independent of the Exchange version. Again, `eseutil -mh` is your friend:
 Format ulVersion: 0x620,17
 Engine ulVersion: 0x620,17
Created ulVersion: 0x620,17
Note how these numbers don't look anything like Exchange versions. -martin

Comment: :- So, how can i get the information about the version of Microsoft exchange server .